# Are static variables in mongoose possible?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, static-variables

I am wondering if there is any way one can implement some sort of *static variable* in Mongoose, which would be useful for example in counters (I am biased by my Java background).

Consider the typical example:

```
var AnimalSchema = new Schema({
    name: String
  , type: String
});
```

How could one implement a *dogs counter*? I am thinking to something like `var dogs=0;`
and a static method like:

```
AnimalSchema.statics.aNewDog= function aNewDog () {
  var dogs++;
}
```

called everytime we create a new Animal of type dog. And similarly a method to get the number of dogs. I suppose this would be computationally less demanding than counting the number of dogs in some sort of loop. 
I hope I made my point, perhaps there is already an easy way to do this.

Comment: why not directly query `dogs` count with mongoose?

Comment: @Chen-TsuLin Thanks. I know that it is possible. My doubt is whether it is more efficient to just read a variable, or to process a query everytime one needs the number of dogs, especially when an elevate number of documents are stored.

Comment: The reason why I thought it's not a good idea is that when you have more than one nodejs programs or mongodb clients, It will be unsync. And It hard to run with other mongodb's feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought it's not a good idea.

When you have more than one nodejs programs or mongodb clients, It will be unsync.

And It's hard to run with other mongodb's features.

But if you still want to do it, you can use mongoose middleware & plugin

```
var dog = 0; // or query dogs count  

function addDogPlugin(schema, options) {

    schema.post('save', function (doc) {
        if (doc.type === 'dog') dog++;
    });
}

AnimalSchema.plugin(addDogPlugin);
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand. Do you mean that this may not be thread-safe?